# How can I create a GPT partition label and mount the partition using its label in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, mount, ubuntu-14.04, gpt

I'm trying to assign a partition label to a GPT partition, and use that partition label as an identifier for mounting in Ubuntu 14.04.

So first I setup GPT and created a partition on the volume:

```
~# parted /dev/vdb -s -- mklabel gpt
~# parted /dev/vdb -s -- mkpart primary 0 -1
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
```

And then I assigned the partition label "TEST" to partition 1:

```
~# parted /dev/vdb -s -- name 1 TEST
```

And formatted the partition with ext4:

```
~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb1
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
6553600 inodes, 26214391 blocks
1310719 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
800 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

From here, I can see that there's a symlink to vdb1 under `/dev/disk/by-partlabel` as expected:

```
~# ls -l /dev/disk/by-partlabel/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 12 13:10 TEST -> ../../vdb1
```

And so I set the contents of my fstab accordingly (saw `PARTLABEL` in [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#GPT_labels)):

```
~# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
PARTLABEL=TEST /opt/ops/backup ext4 defaults 0 0
```

But I'm unable to mount the device using `PARTLABEL=TEST`:

```
~# mount -a
mount: special device PARTLABEL=TEST does not exist
```

Upon further inspection, I noticed that `blkid` is listing `vdb1` without a `PARTLABEL`:

```
~# blkid
/dev/sr0: LABEL="config-2" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/vda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="56ea71ab-5e1b-43ce-a0fb-be31f6f224ac" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/vdb1: UUID="6f446b13-e62a-42c5-953b-68298ab93dbd" TYPE="ext4"
```

I've tried restarting `udev`, but to no avail:

```
~# service udev restart
udev stop/waiting
udev start/running, process 12959
~# blkid
/dev/sr0: LABEL="config-2" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/vda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="56ea71ab-5e1b-43ce-a0fb-be31f6f224ac" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/vdb1: UUID="6f446b13-e62a-42c5-953b-68298ab93dbd" TYPE="ext4"
```

Why might a proper symlink be showing up under `/dev/disk/by-partlabel`, although that label isn't showing up as a `PARTLABEL` value alongside the disk in `blkid`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't figured out why `PARTLABEL=TEST` doesn't work as well as why the labels are not showing up in `blkid`, I just worked around this by mounting via the `/dev/disk/by-partlabel` symlinks:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
/dev/disk/by-partlabel/TEST /opt/ops/backup ext4 defaults 0 0
```

I've decided to go with this for now while working with partition labels in my configuration management, but I'm still very interested in knowing why `blkid` is not displaying the `PARTLABEL` for the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try filesystem labels. For me this works great on several systems.

Use filesystem-tools (e2label, mkfs, ntfslabel etc) or gparted to label the partition after or during formatting.

my fstab looks like this:

```
# <file system>   <mount point>   <type> <options>         <dump>  <pass>
LABEL=KUBUNTU     /               ext4    discard,relatime,errors=remount-ro      0       1
LABEL=UEFI        /media/UEFI     vfat    discard,relatime,noauto                 0       0
LABEL=SWAP        none            swap    sw                                      0       0
LABEL=DATA        /media/DATA     ext4    defaults                                0       2
```

Comment: GPT has labels in addition to the filesystem label.